# PHPmailer multiple mailing - 503 error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with phpmailer. I want to send multiple emails with different content. The script works for several addresses, but not for several hundred. When I try to send emails for 100 users i have error 503 "Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. "

Here is code:

```
include('../config_inc.php');
include('../admin-settings.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require("../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");
    require("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
if(!empty($_POST['wyslijemail'])){
    foreach($_POST['wyslijemail'] as $ids){
        set_time_limit(60);
        $iduser = $ids;
        $tabelka = '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
        $ticket = '';
        for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
            $ticket .= $tabelka[rand()%(strlen($tabelka))];
        }

        $zapytanie_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$iduser."");
        $user_row = mysql_fetch_array($zapytanie_user);
        $admin_email = $settings_cms['email'];
        $title_page = $settings['tytul_email'];
        $login = $user_row['login'];
        $haslo_encode = $user_row['haslo_encode'];
        $tytul_aktywacja = $powiadomienia['tytul_aktywacja'];
        $tresc_aktywacja = $powiadomienia['tresc_aktywacja'];
        $email = $user_row['email'];
        $message = $powiadomienia['aktywacja_oferta'];
        $message = str_replace("{login}",$login,$message);
        $message = str_replace("{domena}",$domena2,$message);
        $message = str_replace("{ticket}",$ticket,$message);
        $message = str_replace("{iduser}",$iduser,$message);
        $message = str_replace("{haslo}",$haslo_encode,$message);
        $message = str_replace("{tytul}",$title_page,$message);
        $message = str_replace("tytul_aktywacja}",$tytul_aktywacja,$message);
        $message = str_replace("tresc_aktywacja}",$tresc_aktywacja,$message);

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->PluginDir = "phpmailer/";
        $mail->From = "".$admin_email."";
        $mail->FromName = "".$settings['tytul_email']."";
        $mail->Host = "".$settings['smtp_serwer']."";
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->Username = "".$settings['smtp_login']."";
        $mail->Password = "".$settings['smtp_haslo']."";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Port = "".$settings['smtp_port']."";
        $mail->SetLanguage("pl", "phpmailer/language/");
        $mail->Subject = $powiadomienia['tytul_aktywacja'];
        $mail->Body = ''.$message.'';
        $mail->AddAddress("".$email."","".$login."");
        if($mail->Send()){
            $check = 1;
        } else {
            header('Location: https://xxx?akcja=email_masowo_error');
        }
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
        }
        if($check == 1){
            header('Location: https://xxxx/show_users_list.php?akcja=email_masowo');
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: may be server problem

Comment: Use sleep(1) after sending email in you if clause and then check how the mail server behaves. Most probably it has setting to accept only limited emails in specific time interval.

Comment: have you tried setting SMTPKeepAlive = true in PHPMailer (i.e. not set-up a new connection for each message),

Comment: please note that you are using a deprecated API mysql_* that have been removed since PHP 7. Also please note that your script is widely open to SQL injections. You should consider switching to prepared statements (supported by both mysqli_* and PDO)

Answer (score 2):

Doing things that take a long time during a web page submission is unreliable, and will get you 503 errors, as the web server figures that PHP is broken. You can increase timeout, but that's not a proper solution.

Use your page submission to mark a message as needing to be sent (but not actually doing the send), then use a cron script, or a long-running daemon to pick up the messages and send them asynchronously. [A suitable script for sending messages to a list efficiently is provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

For ultimate performance, you should run a local mail server and submit to that over SMTP. The PHPMailer wiki has [an article about sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists).

You're running an old version of PHPMailer; [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions; they are obsolete. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.